# is it possible to install openstack controller node in a ubuntu desktop OS

Tags: installation, openstack, desktop, ubuntu-server

is it possible to install openstack controller node in a ubuntu desktop OS or is possible just to install it in a ubuntu server OS.
If is possible just for ubuntu server, how can i access to horizon dashboard ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes - that is perfectly fine. I tend to run Ubuntu Server and install a Desktop on top, but simply running it on a Ubuntu Desktop distro works fine as well.

In the end you may need to install additional packages on Ubuntu Desktop.

Comment: what are the packages I need to install on Ubuntu desktop?

Comment: Mostly things like virtualization packages etc might be installed as part of the server installation, but nothing preventing them from being installed manually or by tooling (e.g. devstack).